# Cannot Find X12 EDI ISA11/ISA16 element in Mule

Tags: mule, x12

I am trying to parse an X12(835) file I am able to see all the elements except ISA11 and 16 elements. But I have all the elements in the input 835. I am using mule 3.7

Answer (score 0):

These elements will be under delimiters section of the hash map object. We will get all the delimiters like component separator, repetition separator, data element separator and segment terminator..